# Expo Cli - Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I faced this issue with the expo client. The project is working on both iOS simulator and Android emulator. But the issue arise when I use expo app on the actual device.

I ran `expo start` and it gave me a QR code to scan, which I scanned from my device. Which displayed this error.

If I replace the Drawer navigator with just home component without `react-navigation` it works. The problem arises when I return `<Navigator />` in my `App.tsx`.

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigator from './navigations';
import {YellowBox, View, Text, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {useFonts} from '@use-expo/font';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['VirtualizedLists should never ']);

const App = () => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Poppins: require('./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf'),
    'Poppins-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf'),
    'Poppins-Light': require('./assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf'),
  });

  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <>
        <Navigator />
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <Text>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

[image]

This is package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.1",
    "@use-expo/font": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-font": "^8.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "~0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.23",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.61.23",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "jest-expo": "~37.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 2 you import

```
import Navigator from 'navigations';
```

In your package.json there is no package that is called navigations. Your idea is to import Navigation from React-Navigation. I'll suggest to you that you read the Getting Started page of React-Navigation:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: Oh! That is imported from `navigation` folder. I have used eslint config to get ride of `./navigation` I will update file to avoid confusion. But as i mentioned it's working on simulator. The issue appears with expo cli